# Hide main form initially...Possible? (VB language)

Tags: vba

Is there a way to start a Windows Forms in (VB language) application with the main window not visible? Then later on when an external event occurs, I want to display the form.
How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: See the 'Visible' property.

Answer (score 0):

Initially you just put:

`Load SuperAmazingForm`

..then when you want to display the form, simply call its `Show` method as normal.

Doing it this way allows you to interact with the form's objects without the user being aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are doing this in Excel/Word or Access. If you are using Excel/Word then the `Load MyForm` syntax works. However, Access uses it's own variation of the standard UserForm. To load a form hidden you can do:`DoCmd.OpenForm "MyAccessForm", WindowMode:=acHidden`.